# Use namespaced variable for indexing in x:Bind?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to bind values defined in the dictionary of the ViewModel to a text in XAML, but the key to the dictionary is an enum in another namespace (coming from a C++/WinRT interface), and it seems I can't use namespaces in the indexer of the dict.

XAML:

```xml
xmlns:winrt="using:Foo_WinRT"
...
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.OptionNames[winrt:OptionsEnum.OptionA]}">
```

ViewModel:

```cs
using Foo_WinRT;
...
IDictionary<OptionsEnum, string> OptionNames { get; }
```

I found a workaround, by using a helper function in the code behind (using the namespaced variable as a regular function parameter in XAML works).

Modified XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind GetOptionName(winrt:OptionsEnum.OptionA)}">
```

View code-behind:

```cs
private string GetOptionName(OptionsEnum option) => ViewModel.OptionNames[option];
```

But writing helper methods everywhere I need something like this seems very tedious, is there any way to make the direct use of the VM dictionary possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation again, I realized that although Dictionaries can be used in x:Bind, but only if they have a string key ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#collections)). So there's no way it will work with an enum like I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use dictionary in xaml to bind with the Text property, you could use `Converter` or your `GetOptionName()` helper method. If you don't want to write the helper methods when you try to bind with dictionary, you can put it in your viewmodel instead of in page. In that case, you don't need to declare the method every time and just call the `ViewModel.GetOptionName()` to bind.

**Converter method:**

```
public class DictionaryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, string language)
    {
        OptionsEnum result;
        var aa = Enum.TryParse<OptionsEnum>(parameter.ToString(), out result);
        var dictionary = value as Dictionary<OptionsEnum, string>;

        return dictionary[result];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.OptionNames,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},ConverterParameter=OptionA}"/>
</Grid>
```

Or **Helper method:**

```
public class MyViewModel {
    ......
    public string GetOptionName(OptionsEnum option) => OptionNames[option];
}
```

.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.GetOptionName(winrt:OptionsEnum.OptionA)}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: It is not impossible to use dictionaries in x:Bind, but they only work with string keys (see my own answer below).
The converter is not a bad idea, but using that I would lose the biggest selling point of x:Bind, compile time type checking.
I think I will just move my helper method to the VM, it seems like the clearest solution.